# Compare of a PDE and ODE

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

On closed smooth convex manifold $M^n\subset \mathbb R^{n+1}$, $H(x,t)$ is mean curvature , $A$ is second fundamental form,  satisfy 
$$
\partial_t H =\Delta H + |A|^2H - |A|^2
$$
Consider ODE
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \varphi=\frac{\varphi^3 - \varphi^2}{n} ~~~~~~~~  \\
\varphi(0)=H_\min(\cdot , 0) >1
$$
How  to prove $H(\cdot, t )\ge \varphi(t)$ for any $t\ge 0$ ?  I try to use maximum principle , but fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $|A|^2 = \sum_i^n \kappa_i^2$ and $H = \sum_i^n \kappa_i$ we have $H^2 \le n |A|^2$. Thus we have $$|A|^2H - |A|^2 = |A|^2 (H-1) \ge \frac 1 n \left(H^3 - H^2\right)$$ whenever $H-1 \ge 0.$

Thus the comparison principle for parabolic PDE gives $H \ge \varphi$ for $\varphi$ any solution of $\varphi'(t) = \frac 1 n \left( \varphi^3 - \varphi^2 \right)$ with $\varphi(0) \le \inf H(\cdot,0)$, *so long as $\varphi - 1 \ge 0.$*

Since this inequality is true by assumption at the initial time, we now just need to show that it is preserved by the ODE. As $F(\varphi) = \frac 1 n \left( \varphi^3 - \varphi^2 \right)$ is locally Lipschitz near $1$ and $\varphi(t) = 1$ is a solution, the uniqueness theorem tells us that a solution that is initially $\ge 1$ cannot fail to be so at a later time.

Comment: Thanks, how the uniqueness theorem make initially $\ge 1$ cannot fail to be so at later ?

Comment: @lanse7pty: If $\varphi < 1$ at some later time then by continuity (intermediate value theorem) it must be equal to $1$ at some time; but then the uniqueness theorem tells us that $\varphi = 1$ for *all* time.

Comment: Could you write the content of comparison principle ? I find the one can't deal the non-linear term.

Comment: @lanse7pty: theorem 6.4 of http://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~andrews/book.pdf